# Repeating numbers in an array of n integers is there in which the range of the elements is n

Tags: arrays, algorithm

An array of n integers is there in which the range of the elements is n. i.e., the difference between maximum and minimum number is n. Find the repeating numbers.

I could not solve this question and actually can`t understand its logic to create a coherent algorithm. Any suggestions?

Comment: Ok if you couldn't come up with any code, you might wanna consider adding an example.

Comment: Is there a constraint as to how many numbers are repeating and how many times a number will repeat?

Comment: finding number of times each number is repeated was asked as a follow up question.

Comment: OK. any constraint on `n` ?

Comment: Nope, no constraint was given.

Comment: What are time and space constraints? May be some LSD radix sort and then iterate over an array to find what you want?

Comment: If 0<n<10^6, you could map the count of numbers on an array. BTW, most languages provide `map` data structure, which can be used to directly count frequency of elements.

Comment: This is a variant of [element distinctness problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Element_distinctness_problem). It is interesting, because it exactly fall to the case where a modification of bucket sort can be used for O(n) solution. Not sure how to make it without linear space though.

Comment: Assuming you cannot use extra memory, sorting etc. on your array, I've written an answer using `inplace hashing` technique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) find the minimum value,

2) initialize an array of `n` counters to `0`,

3) scan the given array and for every element increment the counter with index `e-min`.

The answer is made of all `e` such that their counter is `> 1`. (Note that tri-valued counters `0|1|>1` are enough.)

Comment: This solution assumes that `n` has a reasonable value, while `min` may be arbitrarily large.

Answer (score 3):

Given there are n elements and difference between maximum and minimum elements is n. First convert the array such that all elements are between 1 to n, that is, if initial array was {5,5,7,7,9} it converts to {1,1,2,2,5}.

This is done by subtracting min-1 from every element.
So in the above example we get min = 5, thus {5-4,5-4,7-4,7-4,9-4} = {1,1,2,2,5}.

Now you can use the following pseudo code:

```
for(i=0;i<n;++i)//line 1
    arr[(arr[i]%(n+1))-1] += n+1;
for(i=0;i<n;++i)//line 3
    cout<<"frequency of "<<i+1<<" is "<<(arr[i]/n+1);
```

What we are doing is taking an element arr[i], and adding n+1 at the index value equalling that element(possible because elements between 1 and n), e.g. if we have n = 6 and element = 2 then we add 7 at index '2'.This is because by later dividing with n+1 we get the frequency of the given number at the index.

But now a problem arises, what if we change the value at an array index which we must process later?

For example we have an array {5,5,2,2,3}, we see that  the value '3' has been modified in the array when we process the first 5.

In order to overcome this we perform the mod of arr[i] with (n+1) (line 2) so that we can nullify the (n+1) additions we might have performed earlier in the array and thus we get back the original value which was present in the array.

We get the frequency of each element by dividing the modified array values with n+1 because it gives us the number of times an index got an increment of n+1.

Thus you can get the frequencies of all elements and tell which elements have repeated(by reverse mapping and adding min-1 to the array index value) and also answer the follow-up question in which the frequencies of the repeating elements was asked.

Answer (score 0):

Since the array size is `n` and `n` is the range of numbers, you can clearly do, what is known as `inplace hashing`.

Lets say the numbers in array are in range `[a..b]`, such that `b-a < n`. Then, element (value) `a` maps onto array index `0`, `a+1` maps onto index `1` and so on. Select a large value `v (>b)`. Now, iterate once through the array. At every step, get the value at that index using this expression: `k = (array[index] - a) % v`, where `a` is minimum value in the array. Now, add `v` to `array[k]`.

After this much is done, iterate through the array once and for each index, frequency of element (value) `index + a` in the original array is `(int)(array[index] / v)`. If this value is `0`, that element is absent and if greater than one, that number is repeated.